# WeChat SDK on arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, wechat

I was trying to use `libWeChatSDK.a` library in my iPhone application and on iPhone 5 it works as it should. However I encountered problems with the newest iPhone, it seems that this library does not support `arm64` `architecture`.

The error I've got is the following:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file .../libWeChatSDK.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file .../libWeChatSDK.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SendMessageToWXReq", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WeChatCustomActivity.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_WXApi", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in WeChatCustomActivity.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do you know if there are some kind of workarounds for this problem?

Comment: Getting the WeChat SDK to work in a Swift project: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35862318/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, it's [available](https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/frame?t=resource/res_main_tmpl&lang=zh_CN) now.

But If you're not good at Chinese, just download it by tap [here](https://open.weixin.qq.com/zh_CN/htmledition/res/dev/download/sdk/iOS_SDK-64.zip).

Comment: Even if downloading the latest version from their Chinese website, still can't compile! I get 3 errors => [ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)]

Comment: @oKBo
If you're sure about that you got is the latest version SDK, you'd blame the 'Wechat' official developer cause the mistake, then I'm sure about the [link](https://open.weixin.qq.com/zh_CN/htmledition/res/dev/download/sdk/iOS_SDK-64.zip) is avaliable, I test the fat file via 'lipo -info'.   `Architectures in the fat file: libWeChatSDK.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64` is what I got.

Comment: add this SDK and use these frameworks: SystemConfiguration.framework,libz.dylib,libsqlite3.0.dylib

Answer (score 7):

the link to the arm64 library does work (confirmed) however the code will **not** compile unless you also add **libc++.dylib** library to your project. This is not mentioned in any other links!

I spent hours searching for this. Enjoy.

Comment: lbdakine, nice photo!!:)

Comment: This is the correct answer - now it's finally building.

Answer (score 0):

Don't build your app for architecture arm64. libWeChatSDK.a is apparently only built for 32 bit targets. There is no real penalty for running 32 bit architecture code on the 64bit iPhone/iPads.

Comment: No. Apple requires all apps to have 64-bit support now.

Answer (score 0):

try this
https://github.com/yorkzero831/WechatSDK-in-xcframework
It converted arm64 to sim-arm64 package all libs in sxframework, should solve your problem

Comment: You also don't need to exclude arm on simulator, because it support arm64 armv7 on ios, arm64 x86_64 on simulator