# Pop WeChat/Weixin Safari-like Share Sheet in my app UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, safari, wechat

I'm trying to pop the built in Safari share WeChat in my iOS app. But can't find a way to make WeChat app show up in the UIActivityViewController!

[image]

I noticed that the WeChat app icon shows up when sharing images from the Photo Gallery, and Safari link sharing. The native Notes app doesn't have WeChat option.

Not sure how that's working, any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I ended up downloading their SDK from a link that someone provided here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539049/wechat-sdk-on-arm64/24879548?noredirect=1#comment45184394_24879548

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i could the way for sending multiple images at the same time by using weixin sdk.

Comment: [Here is a guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718897/how-to-add-the-wechat-api-to-a-swift-project) on getting the WeChat SDK set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done using "Share" extensions. See Apple docs for more information: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1

Regarding why some apps appear in certain sharing contexts but not in others, this is because a Share extension has to declare to iOS which kind of data it supports for sharing. Presumably, WeChat developers did not enable their Share extension for "pure" text content, like in the Notes app. See here for how to set which kind of data a Share extension accepts: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW8

Unfortunately you won't be able to add the WeChat Share extension on behalf of them if they didn't allow it, but you might be able to use some WeChat API to develop your own app extension with text content enabled.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was trying to install their SDK, but it doesn't compile on arm64. I even went to their Chinese website to get the most recent version:
https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showdocument?action=dir_list&t=resource/res_list&verify=1&lang=zh_CN

Still can't compile :|

Comment: Good luck with that :) if you encounter problems with their SDK, please post your questions in another thread, as it has nothing to do with the subject discussed here.

Answer (score 2):

`WeChat`'s icon won't appear in `UIActivityViewController` if you try to share anything other than URL. `WeChat` only accepts URL posts. This code snippet should work for you:

```
NSArray *items = @[[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
```