# Integrating WeChat to IOS IPhone App: cannot get asset

Tags: ios, iphone, wechat

I am developing an IOS 8.X app for IPhone using Xcode 6.1.1.; and the plan is to provide Share features for common Social Networks such as Facebook , Twitter and WeChat in Asia.

WeChat requires not only to import library for using their services but also to acquire an asset Id from the following web-site: http://dev.wechat.com

From the communities and the website i can see lots of discussions and help about the actual integration of WeChat into Apps. However, I have never reach more than the login phase. My registration is activated however before being to apply for an asset id from WeChat, it asked me to complete my Profile.

The completion of this Profile results into a window with the single enigmatic text "Failure", no explanation. I tried both on Mac and PC with common browsers + tablet. No success.

I have written to their "support " by email as instructed, no answer; tried also by WeChat to get a bot answering "got it " , "thanks for your request" randomly. In other words, it looks like developers are on their own.

From Stackoverflow, i can see quite a few questions about WeChat integration. However it seems each people has reached more than the login and got their asset.

That's why i am reaching you out : have you met a similar login issue and how did you fix it ? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't get your problem

Answer (score 1):

The most recent asset can be found at the link below.

[WeChat SDK on arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23539049/3904329)

THE KEY TO MAKING THIS WORK IS TO add the libc++.dylib library to your project. This is not mentioned in ANY OTHER LINK! This frustrated me for HOURS until I used google translate to search Chinese websites. enjoy =)