# We-Chat SDK integration iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, wechat

I have searched a lot but I am not getting any of the demo.
How could I go about integrating it into my app?

I checked many sources like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465167/integrating-wechat-to-ios-iphone-app-cannot-get-asset) or [this site](http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi)

Comment: They have provided demo application.. Get it from here http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/download

Comment: I used that demo they are not providing any API integration demo to get Userinfo.

Comment: You can describe what problem you meet.Maybe I can help you.

Comment: @SeanChense,  I want to fetch the user information when i click on "Login with WeChat" button. I am not getting any of the demo where i can see the wechat api integration. Please provide some demo if you know.

Comment: [Here is a Swift guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35862318/3681880) for integrating WeChat into an app.

Comment: Check here for adding login with we chat function to your app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069029/how-do-i-do-authorization-and-login-with-wechat-using-the-ios-sdk/38069132#38069132

Answer (score 3):

Hi I download the English version SDK from the link http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi you provided. It turns out to be missing some methods. In the latest version 1.5 in Chinese(all the comments are Chinese) there are methods like

```
+(BOOL) sendAuthReq:(SendAuthReq*) req viewController : (UIViewController*) viewController delegate:(id<WXApiDelegate>) delegate;
```

and classes:

```
#pragma mark - SendAuthReq
@interface SendAuthReq : BaseReq
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* scope;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* state;
@end

#pragma mark - SendAuthResp
@interface SendAuthResp : BaseResp
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* state;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* lang;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* country;
@end
```

the request method sample:

```
-(void)sendAuthRequest
{ 
    SendAuthReq* req =[[[SendAuthReq alloc ] init ] autorelease ];
    req.scope = @"snsapi_userinfo" ;
    req.state = @"123" ;
    [WXApi sendReq:req]; 
}
```

Here is the Chinese version [download link](https://res.wx.qq.com/open/zh_CN/htmledition/res/dev/download/sdk/iOS2_SDK-64221cbf.zip) if you are interested

Comment: Right! Look for Chinese version

Comment: You also need the openID and access code to do login. Example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069029/how-do-i-do-authorization-and-login-with-wechat-using-the-ios-sdk/38069132#38069132