# weChat SDK Build Errors

Tags: ios, wechat

I'm trying to get weChat SDK working with my app.  I followed the link below to download the arm64 file but had no luck.  I still get the following 3 errors:

[WeChat SDK on arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23539049/3904329)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      +[WeChatApiUtil EncodeBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
      +[WeChatApiUtil NsDataEncodeBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
      +[WeChatApiUtil DecodeWithBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
      +[WeChatApiUtil DecodeBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      +[WeChatApiUtil EncodeBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
      +[WeChatApiUtil NsDataEncodeBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
      +[WeChatApiUtil DecodeWithBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
      +[WeChatApiUtil DecodeBase64:] in libWeChatSDK.a(WeChatApiUtil.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help...

Comment: It's very simple: if you are experiencing this error. You first need the arm64 library mentioned in the link above. the KEY TO MAKING THIS COMPILE IS THE FOLLOWING: you must add the libc++.dylib library to your project. This is not mentioned in ANY OTHER LINK! enjoy =)

Comment: [Here is a guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35862318/3681880) written for Swift but is also useful for Objective C.

Answer (score 14):

THE KEY TO MAKING THIS COMPILE IS THE FOLLOWING: you must add the libc++.dylib library to your project. This is not mentioned in ANY OTHER LINK! I spent probably 30 miserable hours looking for this answer. I hope you find this post in less than 1. enjoy.

Comment: Just went through the same issue, and this definitely solved. Didn't see this library to be mentioned anywhere in documentation.

Comment: awesome. This is not even in their sample app. You saved my day.